# ZipArchive::getStreamIndex kills script

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

I decided to try out the latest `PHP` `ZIP` functions for extracting data and something odd has happened. This `PHP` script is to read data from packed files of a specific extension (`gob` or `goo`) and display them in an `XML` format for further use later.

```php
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zipres = $zip->open($zipfilename);
if($zipres === true)
{
    for($i = 0; $i < $zip->numFiles; $i++)
    {
        echo "\t<entry id=\"".$i."\">".$zip->getNameIndex($i)."</entry>\n";
        if(strripos($zip->getNameIndex($i),".gob") !== false || strripos($zip->getNameIndex($i),".goo") !== false)
        {
            $zipentry = $zip->getStreamIndex($i);
            return;
            if($zipentry)
            {
                $packagenames[] = $zip->getNameIndex($i);
                $wholeGOB[] = stream_get_contents($zipentry);
                fclose($zipentry);
            }
            else
                echo "\t<error>Error reading entry ".$zip->getNameIndex($i)."</error>";
        }
    }
    $zip->close();
}
else
    echo "\t<error>Invalid ZIP file</error>\n\t<code>".$zipres."</code>\n";
```

Having the `return;` before `getStreamIndex` will print out the `<entry>`s, but as soon as I move the `return;` to after `getStreamIndex` I get a blank page (even in `view-source`). Am I doing something wrong, or has this function always been a bit off? And what alternative would you recommend?

Comment: Blank page usually means error, do you have error reporting enabled?

Comment: @ChrisHaas I think so. It reports all other Warnings and Fatals. I just changed the ini settings to E_ALL and still nothing.